# Need to change site URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, url

My site url is

```
http://win-oq2mfmfrk3i:18251/sites/TestSC
```

I need to change it to this:

```
http://MyAnyName.com/sites/TestSC
```

Please suggest me the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps in [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276325(v=office.15).aspx) to extend your current web application into another port/host header configuration.

An alternative is, if you have a reverse proxy or firewall to publish your site, you can configure it to receive the requests under the name you want and forward them to your current site

Answer (score 1):

Their is another way, where you dont need to extend the web application.

1. Create a DNS(MyAnyName.com) pointing to your WFE or Load balancer(if you have)
2. Now update the AAM settings and replace your old URL to new one.
3. Now update the IIS bindings( if any settings over their).